# Management running process

Tags: c#, process-management

I have a console application that runs on my computer. When the application throws an exception, I want to restart the application. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Please rephrase this and give more details...

Comment: _" When the application throws an exception, I want to restart the application."_ No you don't. You want to catch exceptions. And no, you do not do that in `main()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can instantiate a Timer that check every n seconds if the process is alive, for example you can write i function like the following to verify if the process is alive :

```
 public static bool ProcessExist(string processname)
        {
            Process[] aProc = Process.GetProcessesByName(processname);
            return (aProc.Length > 0);
        }
```

Every Tick of the timer you can check if the process is alive or not, if not you can relaunch it.

Another method could be use a [ManagementEventWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.managementeventwatcher.aspx) for get fired an event every time that a process stop on your machine, so for example :

```
ManagementEventWatcher stopWatchProcess = new ManagementEventWatcher(new WqlEventQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_ProcessStopTrace"));
                stopWatchProcess.EventArrived += new EventArrivedEventHandler(stopWatchProcess_EventArrived);
                stopWatchProcess.Start();


private void stopWatchProcess_EventArrived(object sender, EventArrivedEventArgs e) {
            string processName = (string)e.NewEvent.Properties["ProcessName"].Value;
            if(processName == "yourprocess.exe") {
              //Do Something
     }
        }
```